# Analogous for Weierstrass' theorem for functional series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The Weierstrass' theorem for functional series say the following:

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions defined on $E$, and suppose
>   $$|f_n(x)|\leq M_n$$
>   for every $x\in E$ and $n=1,2,3,...$. Then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $E$ if $\sum M_n$ converges.

There exist an analogous theorem for sequence of function instead of series?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ is point-wise convergent to a function $f$ on an interval $I$ and if there's a sequence $\mu_n$ convergent to zero such that

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \mu_n,\quad \forall x\in I$$
then the convergence of $(f_n)$ is uniform.